# How do apply an excel formula to multiple cells at once with changing variables

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

So, disclaimer, I have like, no excel knowledge whatsoever. I want to take online data and bring it into an excel spreadsheet because it would just be so much easier to work with because I have no way to get the program I'm supposed to use to be organized the same way as we organize the paper copy of the same information (alphabetically, and then numerically inside of each letter). The only way to transfer the data is through copy/paste, and it leaves the data with a whole bunch of empty space. I've learned about the TRIM() function, but now I want to apply that to every row in accordance with the data in the rows alongside. I have the data on the same row I want it to be, just a couple columns over. So essentially what I want to do is have A1 = TRIM(C1), A2 = TRIM(C2), B1 = TRIM(D1), B2 = TRIM(D2), so on and so forth. I have about 700 or so lines, and I really don't want to do it by hand. Is there some formula I could just apply to every A cell and just have it display the trimmed version of the C column? Same with B and D.

EDIT: Now, it won't sort right. I'm trying to sort it numerically, but instead of:

1
25
68
203

it's sorting as:

1
203
25
68

Comment: Put `=TRIM(C1)` in `A1` and drag down and across.

Comment: Oh my god thank you. I feel so dumb

Comment: Try `=--TRIM(C1)`. Or maybe just `=--C1`.